# how to force ubuntu disk image mounter to mount image files as writable?

Tags: mount, images, ubuntu-20.04

i have an image and want to edit it a little for some configurations so that they will be available from first boot. but how? i opened the file but the mounted volumes are read-only. when i try `sudo vi [file]` under the mounted directories, and try to save the files, it says that the file in that partition is write-protected, so can't do anything. i tried remounting but doesn't work (even with root rights, it seems the mount points are write-protected from being remounted).

Comment: What type of filesystem exists on the image? "df -T" may help. Some filesystems are read-only by design.

Comment: @fraxinus , it is an img.xz file, within that, is a .img file which has EXT4 and FAT32.

Comment: Did you unzip XZ first?

Comment: @fraxinus , yeah.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled upon this issue as well. The GUI did let me mount a new image as writable, but opening an already existing one always led to read only. This happens even if it is the same that I had just created, unmounted and opened again.

I had a look at the documentation for gnome-disk-image-mounter. I found this:

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter --writable file.img
```

If you run the above without specifying the file, a file picker will open instead.

For more information:

```
man gnome-disk-image-mounter
```

or

```
gnome-disk-image-mounter --help
```

Please remember that permissions still apply to the mounted folder. If it is owned by root and the write flag for the group or user you belong to is not set, then you will not have the permission to edit the mounted partition anyway. But that's an issue of permission rather than read-only mode.

Comment: i am a root user so i should be able to write.

Comment: thanks! it worked! i accepted the answer but couldn't upvote, don't have enough reputation but it says feedback is recorded.